# Manually indexing a record in websolr

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr

Is there any way to index a record manually in websolr.

like in rails code i have get a record

```
user = User.first
# index user in solr?
```

Comment: what do you mean by manually? What is the workflow you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Record gets created but not ready to deliver to users ... so i am not indexing them once the record is ready then it is accessible to users so i would like to make it index (so users can search) once its ready.   

as i am using conditional indexing in my model  

searchable :if => proc { |ready_to_fetch_id| !ready_to_fetch_id.blank? } do

Comment: As I recall, you're using Sunspot. The instance method you're looking for is `user.solr_index`, though I can't immediately recall if the `:if` check is invoked within that method. You should try your question on the [Sunspot user group](http://groups.google.com/group/sunspot-ruby) mailing list.

Comment: Also, I flagged this question as too localized… but perhaps it could be fixed by clarifying the context of the question? Something about how to index a record with Sunspot if it's been marked for exclusion with the `:if` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the [sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) gem...

You can manually index a record with the `solr_index` instance method:

```
user.solr_index
```

At a higher level, if you're trying to limit what records make it into Solr, you can use the `:if` constraint on your `searchable` block:

```
class User
  searchable :if => :active? # assuming the active? method is defined
    # ...
  end
end
```

That way, Sunspot takes care of this for you. No manual `solr_index` required.